# Using AWS for real time location sahring and tracking

Tags: amazon-web-services, geolocation, amazon-dynamodb, real-time, amazon-kinesis-firehose

Brief Solution:

I am storing IOT Device location and Service Provider Cars location in Dynamo DB via AWS Kinesis. 
I am mapping One User with a specific service providers Cars and dispatching the Car to user’s shared location.

Problem: I need to track these mapped (service provider car and user location) on real time on service provider dashboard.
1.  Does DynamoDB offers any direct API to publish and track these location real time?
2.  Do I need to expose these mapped location and track then on dashboard via AWS Kinesis? Does AWS Kinesis offer such APIs?

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using MQTT IoT Core from AWS you have other options.

**Subscribe to MQTT topic directly via WebSockets by AWS JS library.**

You can Use Cognito to manage users and to have some acces to AWS services, this way you can get credentials to subscribe to the topic in MQTT using WebSockets like this link describe.

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/iot/latest/developerguide/protocols.html#mqtt-ws

**Having own Users manager and using a EC2 Instance.**

You can create an EC2 instance and put an AppServer with NodeJs for example and use SocketIO to comunicate to the WebBrowser of users with your own manager, this way they can receive realtime info, whatever you want. You can then use an AWS MQTT IoT NodeJS client and subscribe to the topics you want and just send it by WebSockets of SocketIO server (All this in the same WebApp). This way you need to consider number of users and data in traffic. You can have topics by users for example topics like this "car/tracking/mycarId" where mycarId is an unique Id that identifies this user/car and you canonly subscribe to these you want at the same time, this way you are not subscribed to all topics of your cars and you are not receiving innecesary data and you dont need so much proccess.

I have implemented the second one but now Im migrating my realtime block to Cognito and MQTT via WebSockets.

Regards, Héctor